# Nested for loops in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, nested-loops

In the directory from where I am running a bash script,

directory saved in the variable:

```
ScriptDir=`pwd`
```

I have the following files:

```
B3LYP_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT
B3LYP-D3_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT
PBE_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT
LDA_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT
PBE-D3_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT
PBE0_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT
PBE0-DC_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT

254.186305_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12
252.050453_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12
249.921810_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12
247.812353_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12
245.699603_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12
243.644688_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12
241.581529_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12
239.554134_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12
237.467646_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12
235.473555_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12
```

These files can be classified into two different variables: `DIRS` and `FOLDERS`

```
DIRS="
PBE-D3
PBE
B3LYP
B3LYP-D3
PBE0
PBE0-DC
LDA
"
FOLDERS="
237.467646
239.554134
241.581529
243.644688
245.699603
247.812353
249.921810
252.050453
254.186305
235.473555
"
```

Given this path: `/path/to/target`, If I loop over `DIRS` (`$i`) and `FOLDERS` (`$j`), I would like to end up with the following:

```
ls -lrth /path/to/target/PBE-D3/scaling_volumes/237.467646

237.467646_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12          #   j = 1 on FOLDERS 
PBE-D3_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT               #   i = 1 on DIRS
237.467646.d12

# where `237.467646.d12` is the result of doing:
# cat 237.467646_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12 PBE-D3_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT  >  237.467646.d12

ls -lrth /path/to/target/PBE-D3/scaling_volumes/239.554134

239.554134_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12          #   j = 2 on FOLDERS
PBE-D3_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT               #   i = 1 on DIRS
239.554134.d12

ls -lrth /path/to/target/PBE-D3/scaling_volumes/241.581529

241.581529_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12          #   j = 3 on FOLDERS
PBE-D3_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT               #   i = 1 on DIRS
241.581529.d12

# and so on... 
# In other words, in this iteration, all the `j`th `FOLDERS` for a given `j`th `DIR`

# For the second `DIR`, again the 1st `FOLDER`:
ls -lrth /path/to/target/PBE/scaling_volumes/237.467646

237.467646_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12          #   j = 1 on FOLDERS
PBE_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT                  #   i = 2 on DIRS 
237.467646.d12  

# and so on
```

I have written the following script:

```
DIRS="
PBE-D3
PBE
B3LYP
B3LYP-D3
PBE0
PBE0-DC
LDA
"
FOLDERS="
237.467646
239.554134
241.581529
243.644688
245.699603
247.812353
249.921810
252.050453
254.186305
235.473555
"

ScriptDir=`pwd`

for i in ${DIRS}; do

 cd /path/to/target/$i

 rm -Rf scaling_volumes
 mkdir scaling_volumes

 cd scaling_volumes

 for j in ${FOLDERS}; do
  rm -Rf ${j}
  mkdir ${j}
  cd  $ScriptDir

  cp -avr  ${j}_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12  /path/to/target/$i/scaling_volumes/${j}

  cp -avr ${i}_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT /path/to/target/$i/scaling_volumes/${j}

  cd /path/to/target/$i/scaling_volumes/${j}

  cat ${j}_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12 ${i}_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT > ${j}.d12

  cd  $ScriptDir

  done

done
```

For some reason what I receive is:

```
ls -lrth /path/to/target/PBE-D3/scaling_volumes

235.473555   # Only the last FOLDER has been created
```

or:

```
ls -lrth /path/to/target/PBE/scaling_volumes

235.473555   # Only the last FOLDER has been created
```

where only last `j`th `FOLDER` was created

Comment: You do `cd $ScriptDir` at the end of the loop, the next iteration starts there, but the first iteration starts in `scaling_volumes`.

Comment: Since you are using `bash`, you can use `pushd, popd` in place of `cd` to go in and out of a directory.

Comment: @choroba Thanks a lot for your more than useful great advice (see answer)

Answer (score 1):

- Fail fast, add `|| exit 1` after `cd` and `mkdir` commands
- Avoid `cd` use it only when necessary because paths are absolute

Also script directory can be different from `pwd` (current working directory), for example if script is called from another directory.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, regarding your two bullet points: **1)** could you please expand how would you use `|| exit 1`  here?  **2)** how would you use `cd` here then? In this case the script directory is the same from the working directory

Answer (score 0):

Following @choroba 's great advice, I managed to solve the problem by creating a

```
scaling=`pwd`
```

variable, and place it just before the `for j in ${FOLDERS}` loop, and end this loop with

```
cd  $scaling
```

However, I am very interested in the `|| exit 1` approach suggested by @Nahuel Fouilleul but I am afraid I do not know where to start with.

```
ScriptDir=`pwd`

for i in ${DIRS}; do

 cd /home/david/Trabajo/structures/Trial_for_double_for_loop_in_bash/pob_TZVP/Calcite_I/$i

 rm -Rf scaling_volumes_from_117.743646
 mkdir scaling_volumes_from_117.743646

 cd scaling_volumes_from_117.743646

 scaling=`pwd`

 for j in ${FOLDERS}; do
  rm -Rf ${j}
  mkdir ${j}
  cd  $ScriptDir

  cp -avr  ${j}_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12  /home/david/Trabajo/structures/Trial_for_double_for_loop_in_bash/pob_TZVP/Calcite_I/$i/scaling_volumes_from_117.743646/${j}

  cp -avr ${i}_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT /home/david/Trabajo/structures/Trial_for_double_for_loop_in_bash/pob_TZVP/Calcite_I/$i/scaling_volumes_from_117.743646/${j}

  cd /home/david/Trabajo/structures/Trial_for_double_for_loop_in_bash/pob_TZVP/Calcite_I/$i/scaling_volumes_from_117.743646/${j}

  cat ${j}_TOP_FRAGMENT.d12 ${i}_BOTTOM_FRAGMENT > ${j}.d12

  cd  $scaling

  done

done
```